# how can I see if inside this sentence contains a value from this array, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const variable= ['leisure', 'pool', 'Grill']

const receive = 'i need to know about leisure ?'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const variavel = ['leisure', 'pool', 'Grill'];
const recebe = ' need to know about leisure ?';
const result = variavel.some(item => recebe.includes(item))
console.log(result);
```